# Deleting data on firebase with unique id as reference

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete data on my website using a delete button. The data is displayed into a "#table_body" with a button that is created in a javascript. My idea here is that every line of data has a delete button under it. My problem is how to delete the data based on the unique id/reference id by pressing the delete button.

I have tried naming the ".child('123').remove();" instead of ".child(key).remove();" and it works. however it only deletes the data based on the 123 id. I want it to delete the data with the unique id.
Here is the Javascript code:
[image: Here is how my firebase looks like]

```js
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("User");

rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

  var name = snap.child("name").val();
  var add = snap.child("address").val();
  var contact = snap.child("contact").val();



  $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + add + "</td><td>" + contact +  "</td><td>");
  $("#table_body").append('<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Delete</button></td></tr>');

});

function reply_click(clicked_id){
   firebase.database().ref("User").child(key).remove();
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../assets/img/apple-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../assets/img/favicon.png">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title>
    Happy Paws
  </title>
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />
  <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Material+Icons" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link href="../assets/css/material-dashboard.css?v=2.1.0" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
  <link href="../assets/demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>


  <div class="wrapper ">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color="green" data-background-color="black" data-image="../assets/img/sidebar-2.jpg">
      <!--
        Tip 1: You can change the color of the sidebar using: data-color="purple | azure | green | orange | danger"

        Tip 2: you can also add an image using data-image tag
    -->
      <div class="logo">
        <a class="simple-text logo-normal">
          HAPPY PAWS
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="nav-item active  ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./dashboard.html">
              <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
              <p>Dashboard</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./user.html">
              <i class="material-icons">person</i>
              <p>Account</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./tables.html">
              <i class="material-icons">content_paste</i>
              <p>User List</p>
            </a>
          </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javscript:void(0)" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="material-icons">library_books</i>
                  <span class="notification">Pet Article</span>
                  <p class="d-lg-none d-md-block">
                    Some Actions
                  </p>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="./typography.html"><p style="color:green;">Articles</p></a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="./add-article.html"><p style="color:green;">Add Article</p></a>
             </li>
   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javscript:void(0)" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i>
                  <span class="notification">Products</span>
                  <p class="d-lg-none d-md-block">
                    Some Actions
                  </p>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="./accessories.html"><p style="color:green;">Accessories</p></a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="./clothes.html"><p style="color:green;">Clothes</p></a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="./food.html"><p style="color:green;">Food</p></a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="./hygiene.html"><p style="color:green;">Hygiene</p></a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="./toys.html"><p style="color:green;">Toys</p></a>
                </div>
              </li>
         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="javscript:void(0)" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="material-icons">pets</i>
                  <span class="notification">Pet Adoption</span>
                  <p class="d-lg-none d-md-block">
                    Some Actions
                  </p>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="./icons.html"><p style="color:green;">Dog</p></a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="./cat.html"><p style="color:green;">Cat</p></a>
                </div>
              </li>
        
    <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./login.html">
              <i class="material-icons">logout</i>
              <p>logout</p>
            </a>
          </li>
    
          <!-- <li class="nav-item active-pro ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./upgrade.html">
                    <i class="material-icons">unarchive</i>
                    <p>Upgrade to PRO</p>
                </a>
            </li> -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel">
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent navbar-absolute fixed-top " id="navigation-example">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Dashboard</a>
          </div>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" data-target="#navigation-example">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
            <form class="navbar-form">
              <div class="input-group no-border">
                <input type="text" id="Search1" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                <button type="submit" id="Search2" class="btn btn-default btn-round btn-just-icon">
                  <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                  <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- End Navbar -->
      <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
   <a href="#">
              <div class="card card-stats">
                <div class="card-header card-header-warning card-header-icon">
                  <div class="card-icon">
                    <i class="material-icons">face</i>
                  </div>
                  <p class="card-category">New Users</p>
                  <h3 class="card-title">
                    <small></small>
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <div class="stats">
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <a href="reports.html">
              <div class="card card-stats">
                <div class="card-header card-header-success card-header-icon">
                  <div class="card-icon">
                    <i class="material-icons">report_problem</i>
                  </div>
       <p class="card-link" href="./dashboard.html">
                  <p class="card-category" >Reports</p>
                  <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
      
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <div class="stats">
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
   <a href=".">
              <div class="card card-stats">
                <div class="card-header card-header-danger card-header-icon">
                  <div class="card-icon">
                    <i class="material-icons">pets</i>
                  </div>
                  <p class="card-category">New Pet for Adoption</p>
                  <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <div class="stats">
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
   <a href="#">
              <div class="card card-stats">
                <div class="card-header card-header-info card-header-icon">
                  <div class="card-icon">
                    <i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i>
                  </div>
                  <p class="card-category" href="./dashboard.html">New Product</p>
                  <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <div class="stats">
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
   <a href="#">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header card bg-success text-white">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Account List</h4>
                 
                </div>
                <div class="card-body table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead class="text-warning">
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Address</th>
                      <th>Contact</th>
                      <th>Delete</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="table_body">
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.8/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBHzWLC1UCPrwI0lTsWdmTQWlles05unb0",
    authDomain: "happy-paws-6f139.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://happy-paws-6f139.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "happy-paws-6f139",
    storageBucket: "happy-paws-6f139.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "53124089069"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="accountview.js"></script>
<script src="firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="login.js"></script>

  <div class="fixed-plugin">
    <div class="dropdown show-dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"> </i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="header-title"> Sidebar Filters</li>
        <li class="adjustments-line">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="switch-trigger active-color">
            <div class="badge-colors ml-auto mr-auto">
              <span class="badge filter badge-purple active" data-color="purple"></span>
              <span class="badge filter badge-azure" data-color="azure"></span>
              <span class="badge filter badge-green" data-color="green"></span>
              <span class="badge filter badge-warning" data-color="orange"></span>
              <span class="badge filter badge-danger" data-color="danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="header-title">Images</li>
        <li>
          <a class="img-holder switch-trigger" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <img src="../assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a class="img-holder switch-trigger" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <img src="../assets/img/sidebar-2.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="img-holder switch-trigger" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <img src="../assets/img/sidebar-3.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="img-holder switch-trigger" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <img src="../assets/img/sidebar-4.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        
        
       
  <!--   Core JS Files   -->
  <script src="../assets/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/core/bootstrap-material-design.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/default-passive-events"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
  <script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>
  <!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>
  <!-- Chartist JS -->
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/chartist.min.js"></script>
  <!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
  <!-- Control Center for Material Dashboard: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
  <script src="../assets/js/material-dashboard.js?v=2.1.0"></script>
  <!-- Material Dashboard DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! -->
  <script src="../assets/demo/demo.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $().ready(function() {
        $sidebar = $('.sidebar');

        $sidebar_img_container = $sidebar.find('.sidebar-background');

        $full_page = $('.full-page');

        $sidebar_responsive = $('body > .navbar-collapse');

        window_width = $(window).width();

        $('.fixed-plugin a').click(function(event) {
          // Alex if we click on switch, stop propagation of the event, so the dropdown will not be hide, otherwise we set the  section active
          if ($(this).hasClass('switch-trigger')) {
            if (event.stopPropagation) {
              event.stopPropagation();
            } else if (window.event) {
              window.event.cancelBubble = true;
            }
          }
        });

        $('.fixed-plugin .active-color span').click(function() {
          $full_page_background = $('.full-page-background');

          $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');

          var new_color = $(this).data('color');

          if ($sidebar.length != 0) {
            $sidebar.attr('data-color', new_color);
          }

          if ($full_page.length != 0) {
            $full_page.attr('filter-color', new_color);
          }

          if ($sidebar_responsive.length != 0) {
            $sidebar_responsive.attr('data-color', new_color);
          }
        });

        $('.fixed-plugin .background-color .badge').click(function() {
          $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');

          var new_color = $(this).data('background-color');

          if ($sidebar.length != 0) {
            $sidebar.attr('data-background-color', new_color);
          }
        });

        $('.fixed-plugin .img-holder').click(function() {
          $full_page_background = $('.full-page-background');

          $(this).parent('li').siblings().removeClass('active');
          $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');


          var new_image = $(this).find("img").attr('src');

          if ($sidebar_img_container.length != 0 && $('.switch-sidebar-image input:checked').length != 0) {
            $sidebar_img_container.fadeOut('fast', function() {
              $sidebar_img_container.css('background-image', 'url("' + new_image + '")');
              $sidebar_img_container.fadeIn('fast');
            });
          }

          if ($full_page_background.length != 0 && $('.switch-sidebar-image input:checked').length != 0) {
            var new_image_full_page = $('.fixed-plugin li.active .img-holder').find('img').data('src');

            $full_page_background.fadeOut('fast', function() {
              $full_page_background.css('background-image', 'url("' + new_image_full_page + '")');
              $full_page_background.fadeIn('fast');
            });
          }

          if ($('.switch-sidebar-image input:checked').length == 0) {
            var new_image = $('.fixed-plugin li.active .img-holder').find("img").attr('src');
            var new_image_full_page = $('.fixed-plugin li.active .img-holder').find('img').data('src');

            $sidebar_img_container.css('background-image', 'url("' + new_image + '")');
            $full_page_background.css('background-image', 'url("' + new_image_full_page + '")');
          }

          if ($sidebar_responsive.length != 0) {
            $sidebar_responsive.css('background-image', 'url("' + new_image + '")');
          }
        });

        $('.switch-sidebar-image input').change(function() {
          $full_page_background = $('.full-page-background');

          $input = $(this);

          if ($input.is(':checked')) {
            if ($sidebar_img_container.length != 0) {
              $sidebar_img_container.fadeIn('fast');
              $sidebar.attr('data-image', '#');
            }

            if ($full_page_background.length != 0) {
              $full_page_background.fadeIn('fast');
              $full_page.attr('data-image', '#');
            }

            background_image = true;
          } else {
            if ($sidebar_img_container.length != 0) {
              $sidebar.removeAttr('data-image');
              $sidebar_img_container.fadeOut('fast');
            }

            if ($full_page_background.length != 0) {
              $full_page.removeAttr('data-image', '#');
              $full_page_background.fadeOut('fast');
            }

            background_image = false;
          }
        });

        $('.switch-sidebar-mini input').change(function() {
          $body = $('body');

          $input = $(this);

          if (md.misc.sidebar_mini_active == true) {
            $('body').removeClass('sidebar-mini');
            md.misc.sidebar_mini_active = false;

            $('.sidebar .sidebar-wrapper, .main-panel').perfectScrollbar();

          } else {

            $('.sidebar .sidebar-wrapper, .main-panel').perfectScrollbar('destroy');

            setTimeout(function() {
              $('body').addClass('sidebar-mini');

              md.misc.sidebar_mini_active = true;
            }, 300);
          }

          // we simulate the window Resize so the charts will get updated in realtime.
          var simulateWindowResize = setInterval(function() {
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
          }, 180);

          // we stop the simulation of Window Resize after the animations are completed
          setTimeout(function() {
            clearInterval(simulateWindowResize);
          }, 1000);

        });
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Javascript method's body can be found in assets/js/demos.js
      md.initDashboardPageCharts();

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Here is how my page looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `key`, you can do the following:

```
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
  var key     = snap.key;
  var name    = snap.child("name").val();
  var add     = snap.child("address").val();
  var contact = snap.child("contact").val();

  $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + add + "</td><td>" + contact +  "</td><td>");
  $("#table_body").append('<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(' + key + ')">Delete</button></td></tr>');

});
 
function reply_click(clicked_id){
  firebase.database().ref("User").child(clicked_id).remove();
}
```

The `snap.key` will be able to retrieve the unique id in the database.

From the docs:

> [`key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key)
>
> The key (last part of the path) of the location of this DataSnapshot.

Comment: it doesn't work sir. i also tried replacing the                                                            
'<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Delete</button></td></tr>'                                             into                                                                                                                  
'<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(key)">Delete</button></td></tr>'                 
 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @LancerEX have a look at the update (with `onClick="reply_click(key)"` -that I added to Peter's answer) we were actually passing the string value "key" to the `reply_click` function. Now, with `onClick="reply_click(' + key + ')"` it should be ok.

Comment: it still doesn't work. I think the problem is within my "function reply_click" but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you console.log the `key` in the function and under `onchildadded`

Comment: Your function code should be like: `firebase.database().ref("User").child(clicked_id).remove();`

Comment: @PeterHaddad Sorry to intervene so much on your answer!! :-)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec its fine, no worries!!

Comment: it worked! thanks to both of you guys. appreciate it :)